# Access violation reading location when using ITK filters

Tags: vtk, itk

I am writing a very simple program that:

- 1 - Reads a `.vtk` file using `itk::MeshFileReader`
- 2 - Decimates the mesh using `SquaredEdgeLengthDecimationQuadEdgeMeshFilter`

During step 2, I get an `Access violation reading location` error.

This crash happens for certain `.vtk` file and doesn't happen for others.

Have you encountered such error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in `SquaredEdgeLengthDecimationQuadEdgeMeshFilter`, or, less likely, in [MeshFileReader](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/tree/master/Modules/IO/MeshVTK).

Have you tried it with the latest stable [release](https://itk.org/ITK/resources/software.html) (v4.13) or the git [master](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK)? If not, try that first. If the problem still persists, report the issue on ITK [forum](https://discourse.itk.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`SquaredEdgeLengthDecimationQuadEdgeMeshFilter` expects a QuadEdge mesh input, which is only a subset of all possible geometries that can be saved within .vtk file. E.g. you can have a non-manifold stored as .vtk, in which case you cannot expect sane results when you run a QuadEdgeMeshFilter on it.

What I consider a bug is that the filter doesn't check this precondition; I would think throwing an exception would be appropriate in such case.

Unfortunately I don't know how to check whether an input mesh is a valid input mesh. But I have successfully avoided crashes in this filter by:

- making sure the input has only one connected component (`vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter`)
- cleaning up with `vtkCleanPolyData` with PointMerging turned on

before converting to itk::QuadEdgeMesh and feeding it to  `SquaredEdgeLengthDecimationQuadEdgeMeshFilter`.

On Linux you can use valgrind to check for memory issues, it will point out to you if/where there are memory issues when the filter is run. Preprocessing with the above two filters fixed the memory issues/crashes for my surfaces and the run under valgrind comes out clean.

EDIT: Below code for illustration:

```
#include <vtkPolyDataReader.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter.h>
#include <vtkCleanPolyData.h>

#define VTK_CREATE(type, name) vtkSmartPointer<type> name = vtkSmartPointer<type>::New();

...
VTK_CREATE(vtkPolyDataReader, reader);
reader->SetFileName("/tmp/mesh.vtk");

VTK_CREATE(vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter, connFilter);
connFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
connFilter->SetExtractionModeToLargestRegion();

VTK_CREATE(vtkCleanPolyData, cleaner);
cleaner->SetInputConnection(connFilter->GetOutputPort());
cleaner->SetPointMerging(1);
cleaner->Update();

// Now either convert it to itk::QuadMesh, or if you don't have a converter, just do another I/O
// itk::QuadEdgeMesh<double, 3> MeshType;
// MeshType::Pointer inputItk = PolyDataToItkMesh<MeshType>(cleaner->GetOutput());

VTK_CREATE(vtkPolyDataWriter, writer);
writer->SetInputData(cleaner->GetOutput());
writer->SetFileName("/tmp/mesh_processed.vtk");
writer->Update();
```

Comment: Can you please provide code of how you use the mentioned filters?

Comment: I added code you can use to test your data against.